# Upgrading Google Maps API V2 to V3

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, maps

While finishing a project at [My Map](http://cspc.net/resources/neighborhood-map), I discovered that the API, V2, would no longer be supported as of 2013. I'm beginning to think through the upgrade process.

I have this

```
 function initialize() {
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(24.886436490787712, -70.2685546875);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var bermudaTriangle;

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
      myOptions);

  var triangleCoords = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
    new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
    new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.75737),
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262)
  ];

  // Construct the polygon
  // Note that we don't specify an array or arrays, but instead just
  // a simple array of LatLngs in the paths property
  bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: "#FF0000",
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });

  bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
}
```

as described at on the V3 documentation. I understand, however, that v3 doesn't utilize GXmlHttp which I use in my current implementation. I'm assuming I should go a route similar to [Use Php MySQL w/ V3](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3.html)..but I'm a bit stumped as to how to utilize this method with the Point in Polygon function I have.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can guess `GXmlHttp` is just an AJAX request wrapper.

Use a library like jQuery to do the AJAX request.

You haven't actually demonstrated your problem in your code so it's hard to tell what you want to do with it.

Comment: Thanks, @fire. I just realized that I would need to upgrade..just looking for some input before I dive in.

Comment: Re: Point in Polygon. GMap V3 has a new utility function containsLocation(point, polygon);  See [Geometry Library reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#poly)